# How do AssemblyInfo attributes map to Win32 VERSIONINFO?

Tags: .net, versioning, versioninfo

When you view the properties for a binary file that contains a VERSIONINFO resource, Windows adds a "Version" tab, which displays that information.

Is there a list of which .NET assembly attributes map to which VERSIONINFO fields, so we can control these easily for our .NET assemblies?

Comment: Here's how the latest C# compiler currently does it:  http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/CvtRes.cs,499

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Concerning the "fixed Info":**

PRODUCTVERSION and FILEVERSION are set from `[AssemblyInformationalVersion]` and   `[AssemblyFileVersion]` respectively.

FILEOS, FILETYPE are most likely set by the compiler.

**Concerning the [Var File Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381057(VS.85).aspx)**

`[AssemblyCulture]` maps to "Translation" (I guess!)

**Concerning the [String File Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381049(VS.85).aspx)**

`[AssemblyCompany]` maps to "CompanyName"
`[AssemblyDescription]` maps to "Comments"
`[AssemblyFileVersion]` maps to "FileVersion"
`[AssemblyTitle]` maps to "FileDescription"
`[AssemblyInformationalVersion]` maps to "ProductVersion"
`[AssemblyProduct]` maps to "ProductName"
`[AssemblyCopyright]` maps to "LegalCopyright"

I think "InternalName" and "OriginalFile" are set to the name of the DLL or EXE, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The [`[AssemblyFileVersion]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) attribute (among others) does this, I believe - for example:

```
[assembly:AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
```

You should be able to find this setting in the default `AssemblyInfo.cs` file generated by the IDE; if not, declare it yourself (as above).

You might also want to look generally at the "Assembly Information..." dialog in project properties, which provides access to this and others.

Comment: If possible, I want a complete list that, for each entry in VERSIONINFO, shows me which attribute to include. For example, which attribute do I use for VERSIONINFO's Comments field?