# Is there an equivelant to 'AssemblyInfo.cs' in a Win32 DLL project?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, assemblyinfo

I already looked at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629206/how-do-assemblyinfo-attributes-map-to-win32-versioninfo), but I need the answer flipped around. How would I set the assembly information attributes* in a Win32 DLL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out with a little more looking.

- Right click the Visual Studio Project, and select Add -> Resource..
- Select 'Version', then click 'New...'

Visual Studio will generate the files for you, and you can simply edit the information.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean a native (unmanaged) DLL? Native DLLs don't have an assembly version, they have a version info.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am looking for (you tell me you're the expert here). Basically I have a framework of five .NET assemblies and this one Win32 assembly, and I would like the assembly information to match so this one DLL does not look like an odd one of the batch (like it was hacked/modded/changed/etc)

Comment: Okay, see my answer above. I did a little more looking while waiting for an answer and figured it out. Posted the solution for others to see. (Saying VERSIONINFO really helped my Google query! Thanks!)