# Where to find the assembly configuration information?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo

in AssemblyInfo.cs file I have following subection:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
```

Where this information can be seen after assembly is built ? Since there is nothing about it in file details:

[image]

where else can it be found ?

Regards

Answer (score 13):

You can use reflection to get this information. I believe it would be something like the following.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(true);
var config = attributes.OfType<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
if (config != null) {
        Debug.WriteLine(config.Configuration);
}
```

Thinking about it further is this your intent?

[How to check if an assembly was built using Debug or Release configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186613/how-to-check-if-an-assembly-was-built-using-debug-or-release-configuration)

The blogpost linked from the top answer shows a better way to determine if the assembly is Debuggable: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/determine-whether-an-assembly-was-compiled-in-debug-mode/

One answer indicates that if you use the AssemblyDescription attribute to conditionally include Release/Debug in the text you can have that information in Windows Explorer.

Comment: The third line I would replace with `var config = attributes.OfType<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();`. Then you don't need the cast and it looks a bit cleaner imho.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ILDASM.exe** to look at the compiled assembly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605.aspx for info on using ILDASM.exe.

Or you may use Reflection to look at it via code, such as
`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes()`

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Explorer property sheet pulls that information from the win32 [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) resources. A number of assembly attributes can be [mapped to win32 resource fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629206/how-do-assemblyinfo-attributes-map-to-win32-versioninfo) (and will be set by the build) but it may be that the `AssemblyConfiguration` attribute is not one of them.

If you want to look at all assembly attributes, including those that don't set win32 resource fields, [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx) is one option.